# Just copy a substring in java

Tags: java, string, copy, substring

I have many Strings, for example Animal.dog , World.game , and I want to take only the string before the full stop. e.g I need Animal and World

I don't want to use indexOf() method,or search for a substring since some names are the same e.t.c

Is there any alternative way to achieve that? e.g copy the string until the full stop.

Since the length of the string before the full stop is not constant each time.

Comment: What is a full stop?  And what do you mean some names are the same that you can't use the indexOf method with?

Comment: Is it one big string or do you have several strings?

Comment: you can split the string on the basis of DOT and use the first element from the return array.

Comment: How exactly are your strings "formatted"? One string or more?

Comment: I mean the dot . by full stop :p

Comment: I have an array list of strings like the above strings Animal.dog or World..game or Ingredients.dosage

Comment: split("\\.") was the solution, thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

You just need to split the string using the dot as the separator.

`String.split` returns an array of all the resulting substrings, so:

```
String str = "Animal.dog";
String[] split_str = str.split("\\.");
```

split_str will be:

```
["Animal", "dog"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `split()`, (it probably internally uses `indexOf()`)

```
String partBeforeFullStop = string.split("\\.")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always going to be one period in the string, you can split the string with period as delimiter and take the first string from the array.